# DocuSign - Add pre-fill tabs through JSON marker

Tags: docusignapi

I'm creating a html document and want to place tabs using [JSON markers](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/responsive/setting-tabs/). This method works for common tabs of signers. However, I want to add pre-fill tabs for senders using the same approach but all pre-fill tabs are not showing up.

I'm using [CompositeTemplate](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/templates/composite/) to generate the envelope. As pre-fill tabs don't belong to any recipients, so I put them under document level. The code snippet looks like

```
EnvelopeDefinition().apply {
  emailSubject = ...
  emailBlurb = ...
  this.status = "created"
  compositeTemplates = listOf(
    CompositeTemplate().apply {
      document = Document().apply {
        documentId = "1"
        name = "some document.pdf"
        htmlDefinition = "<div>{{\"tabLabel\": \"exampleTextTab\"}}</div>"
        tabs = Tabs().apply {
          prefillTabs = listOf(
            PreFillTab().apply {
              tabLabel = "exampleTextTab"
              font = "arial"
              fontSize = "size8"
              locked = "true"
            }
          )
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-fill tabs don't currently work with Composite Templates. DocuSign internal ticket TT-5404

### Solutions

Will your API program be setting the values of the pre-fill tabs? If so, then don't use pre-fill tabs. Instead:

- use regular tabs with the first signer
- set the `locked` attribute to `true`

This makes the tabs read-only and they will be visible to all recipients. This will have the same effect as your API application adding and setting pre-fill tabs to the envelope.

Pre-fill tabs are needed when the ***Sender*** needs to fill in the values and the Sender is not one of the recipients of the envelope.

For an API program that uses the ***Sender View*** to enable the Sender to review the envelope and fill in pre-fill tabs, there are some options:

- Your API application can ask the Sender for the pre-fill tab values. Your application can then set those values as regular (locked) tabs as described above.
- Or you could add the pre-fill tabs to the template itself.
- Or (I have not tried this), instead of adding the pre-fill tabs as part of the composite template object, make an additional API call to add the pre-fill tabs by using [EnvelopeDocumentTabs:create](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocumenttabs/create/)

Comment: Thanks, Larry! You read my mind. Currently, I'm using `locked` attribute to achieve the same goal. The only reason that I would love to choose pre-fill tabs over regular tabs and making them read-only is because our senders will be in Sender View before sending an envelope, and we usually have more than 1 recipient. So for a specific field, senders may see multiple tabs overlap each other and they also have to fill each tab with the same value. I guess a pre-fill tab can get it done in one shot. Is there any way to improve this kind of experience?

Comment: And I tried your last option, no luck it didn't work through EnvelopeDocumentTabs:create :(

Comment: Set the tab's `shared` attribute to `true`. It will then be visible to all recipients--so you won't need multiple tabs.

Comment: Thanks, Larry. It really helps, just accepted your first reply :+1

Comment: Oh one last thing, more of a curious question, I tried putting tabs under document level with `recipientId` in each but didn't work, they only show up when I put them under a recipient. Wondering what's the use case of placing tabs under a document?

Comment: Only pre-fill tabs go under document object. But that pattern doesn't work at this time. (Note bug number above)